# CSS empty space to the left of each navbar button

Tags: css

I have a media query to make my navbar buttons vertical on small screens, but when this happens [there is blank space to the left of each button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mouCV.png) and I don't know why, as there is no left margin in my code. Thanks in advance to anyone who can get rid of this.

CSS:

```
/* Navbar */
#navbar {
    background-color: #599;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: centre;
    font-family: 'corbel','arial';
    text-align: center; 
}

#nav_li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav_a {
    text-decoration: none;  
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}



/* Media queries for smaller screens*/
@media screen and (max-width : 350px){

    /* reduce padding */
    header nav a{padding:.7em .7em; }
    [role=main]{padding:1.5em 1.5em;}

    /* make navbar vertical */
    #nav_li{text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;}
    #nav_li, #navbar_a{width: 100%;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id='navbar'>
    <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='gallery.html'>Gallery</a></li>
    <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='testimonials.html'>Testimonials</a></li>
    <li id='nav_li'><a id='nav_a' href='contact.html'>Contact </a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default UL Element Take some padding from left. You need to add below css to resolve this:

```
#navbar {
    padding: 0px;
}
```